# Creating multiple runloops that share data

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am fetching data from a server every 5 seconds updating a list. In addition I am also listening to a button press.

So what I need are two independent loops (pulling data and listening to a physical button on a Raspberry Pi via GPIO) and both need access to a shared list.

For just one loop I could use a simple `while = True` with a `time.sleep(5.0)` but how can I work with two infinite run loops at the same time that both access a shared variable and don’t block each other? Also pressing the button should always be responsive.

How can I do this? Do I need threads for this?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could use `asyncio`

Comment: @WayneWerner I am on Python 2.7. Is asyncio still an option there?

Comment: If you want to use `asyncio` in python 2.7, you can use [Trollius](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius)

Comment: As @DrK mentions, trollius is the backport of asyncio on Python2

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am understanding you correctly, the problem is that you want a button-checking loop that loops every, say, millisecond, while your server polling loop should only run every 5 seconds. Is that correct?

The simple solution would be to just have the server polling code execute inside the faster loop every time 5 seconds have passed since the last poll.
If the poll is time consuming and it becomes a problem that the button detection is blocked during the poll, I think you will have to run the two loops in parallel processes. However, that makes the problem more complex, especially since they are sharing resources.

To implement the 5 second interval inside the fast loop, you could do something like

```
import datetime

# [...] other code

# inside fast loop
if last_poll_time - datetime.now() >= 5:
    poll_again()
    last_poll_time = datetime.now()
```